# Solidity: Get mapping from Struct

Tags: solidity

I'm kinda new to Solidity, sorry for this in advance. I'm building a Dapp and cannot understand how to get a mapping or an array from a Struct. This is the struct that have inside a two mappings and one array.

```
struct Something {
    uint256 var;
    string[] array;
}
```

This is the result printed in the console:

```
{
    var: "17"
}
```

As you can see, the call returns only level one attributes.

How to get that array from the struct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like `contract.methods._tasks(i)._freelancerArray[index]` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible in solidity for a function to return a variable of type mapping.

The default getter of a public struct variable will not return dynamic data types like mapping or dynamic array.

To access data from dynamic field inside an struct you have to implement your own getter.

```
function getTaskFreelancer(uint256 taskId, uint256 idx) public view returns (addres) {
    require(_tasks[taskId]._freelancerArray.length > 0, "Invalid freelancer index");
    return _tasks[taskId]._freelancerArray[idx];
}
```

Comment: Returning structs is possible with [Abi Encoder v2](https://blog.ricmoo.com/solidity-abiv2-a-foray-into-the-experimental-a6afd3d47185), but anyone reading this should be warned: as of January 2020, v2 is highly experimental and should not be used in production.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg But you cannot return a struct that has a mapping from a public/external function.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is the way to do the thing.

Comment: @Ismael interesting, I thought that v2 covered that.